# Prompt for credentials in a batch script

Tags: windows, networking, cmd.exe

I am trying to perform a network copy of files via a batch script. However, as usual there are some networks where the `'copy'` command fails saying `'Bad username or password'.`

And when I try using xcopy, it never works.

I have also tried using,

```
net use \\server\ password /user:domain\username
net use \\server\ipc$ /user:domain\username password
```

But none of these work. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? I was also wondering if it is possible to prompt the ususal Windows login dialog for this...(just an idea)

Any leads on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you don't have to put a username in, it should prompt for that. and  you want a drive letter like Z: after use, and you can't just specify the name of the server you need to specify the name of the share too, and no need to end it with the trailing \(like you did \\server\)  So net use Z: \\server\folder

Answer (score 1):

According to `net help use`, giving a password `*` will ask for the password on the console prompt.

For `net use`, you will also need to specify a device name (which can also be `*`, in which case the system uses the next available name), so you could try (untested)

```
net use * \\server\share * /user:domain\username
```

This should attempt to login to `\\server\share` with `domain\username`, and ask for a password on the console. After that, this share is available via some disk name, but should also be available using the UNC path (as it's successfully logged on)

Comment: You cannot use the UNC name from a batch file, though (unless with `pushd`).

Comment: `dir \\server\share` works for me. pushd seems to work around a general limitation of the command line (being unable to enter a UNC path directly), batch file or not.

Comment: Ah, then it's just that the current directory cannot be an UNC path. Sorry.

Comment: yeah can't CD to a UNC.. an article about it here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/02/15/1683851.aspx